# Eclipse Object adornments don't display for Mercurial Repository

Tags: android, eclipse, mercurial, warnings, mercurialeclipse

In a standard `Android` project, if there are any warnings there will be a corresponding [Warning Icon](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) as well as underlined text to clearly demonstate a potential issue.

However, if you choose to clone an existing `Mercurial` repository, these warning icons are no longer displayed.  Is there any way to show warnings and errors in a project that was created by cloning a `Mercurial` repository?

[image]

The file on the left is from a local `Android` project.  The file on the right is a Project that was cloned from a `Mercurial` repository.  Notice there are no squiggly underline warnings on the file on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the .project file in the two situations. The .project file is found at the root of the Eclipse project and determines which plugins and builder are enabled for the project.  Most likely the fix is to commit the correctly configured project file so that new clones have the same configuration.

Comment: Hey @johnpeb, I noticed that the .project files are different. After committing changes and pushing those changes for the Mercurial project the .project file did not update. I tried to copy the structure of the local (non mercurial) .project file to see if that would resolve the issue but it did not.